# template function within non template class does not link

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I can not link template functions within non template class
I have:

```
class base {};
class mgr : base
{
    template function a;
    ........
    non template functions
};
```

template a access variables of class `m`
for example

```
static m<T>* ptr;
ptr = reinterpret_cast<m<T>*>( std::get<0>(d) );
ptr->m<T>::clear();
(m private section is friend of mgr)
```

in class `g` I want to use function `a`

```
static mgr mg; 
mgr *p = &mg;

m<T> v = *( reinterpret_cast<T*>( p->a(p1,p2) );
note that func. a() return pointer to base (similar idea to void*) regardless of <T>
```

at the end of `m.cpp` I have (per specialization)
example:

```
template class m<string>;
```

at the end of `mgr.cpp` I have (per specialization)
example:

```
template pbase mgr::a<string>( ... );
```

hpp files used for declarations, 
cpp files for definition (implementation)

watching the link map I can see that `mgr` linked template specialized 
function `a`
however it failed to link it in `g`

any help would be appreciated

here is more code 
mgr.hpp

```
#ifndef __mgr__mgr___
#define __mgr__mgr___

#include <iostream>         // cout
#include <ostream>         // cout
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

#include <limits>
#include <climits>
#include <exception>



using namespace std;

    typedef string tInstName;
    enum  tInstType { Typ1 , Typ2 , Typ3 };


    class mgr
    {
        public:
        class MIObase {};

        map<string,tuple<MIObase*,string,tInstType>> Imap;
        template <class T> MIObase* getInstance (  const string& name , const iName& instname  );

    };
#endif
```

mgr.cpp

```
#include <ostream>     
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>   
#include <tuple>   
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

#include <limits>
#include <climits>
#include <exception>


#include "mgr.hpp"
#include "mfunc.hpp"

using namespace std;

        template<>
        pMIObase mgr::getInstance<string> (  const string& filename , const string& name )
        {

            tuple<pMIObase,string,tInstType> d;
            static mfunc<string>* ptr;
            static pMIObase ptr_;


            auto it = Imap.find ( instname );
            if ( it != Imap.end() ) 
            {
                d=Imap[instname];
                ptr = reinterpret_cast<mfunc<string>*>( std::get<0>(d) );
                ptr->mfunc<string>::clear();
                ptr_ = std::get<0>(d);
                cout<<instname <<" already exists .......\n";
                return ptr_;
            }
            else
            {
                //mfunc<string> I;
                ptr = new mfunc<string>;


                d = make_tuple (reinterpret_cast<pMIObase>(ptr),name,Tstr);
                Imap[instname] = d;

                ptr->clear();
                ptr_ = reinterpret_cast<pMIObase>(ptr);
                return ptr_;
            }
        }


    template pMIObase mgr::getInstance<string>(const string& filename , const tInstName& instname);
```

g.cpp

```
#include "mgr.hpp"

using namespace std;

void g()
{
    static mgr mb;
    mgr *pMIO=&mb;  

    // this one dose not link
    static mfunc<string> &v =  *( reinterpret_cast<mfunc<string>*>( pMIO->mgr::getInstance<string> (  ) ));
}
```

Comment: Your omitting of code is confusing, but this looks like the violation of the rule that the compiler has to see an explicit specialization of a template before you're allowed to use the template with matching types, otherwise the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Could you reproduce it in a simple example? It is a little bit unclear what you have there and what you forgot to link, or what is not known by compiler (as @SebastianRedl said).

Comment: As already mentioned, can you please rephrase your question. I am not able to locate class g in the given code.

Comment: in the added code "g" is a function just to show the way i'm calling mgr

Comment: What compiler are you using? This (once stripped of code that is missing in the sample) compile, links and runs fine with clang++. It could be that the explicit instantiation needs to be moved to the header.

Comment: What means: *it failed to link it in `g`*? What is the exact error message? BTW, if you really want help here, you should try to build a [mcve]...

Comment: fails means "undefined reference"

Comment: i feel bad about it ... few typos and it's working. thanks a lot for your time & effort